# visibility binding with converter and no path

Tags: .net, wpf

Visibility="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource nVis}}"

My converter return collapsed if object is nothing and visible if not.

Why the error :

Erreur  1   Erreur de génération inconnue, 'MC3045 : propriété 'Converter' inconnue pour le type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' rencontrée lors de l'analyse d'une expression Markup Extension.

Comment: where is the Path='propertyName' in binding...

Comment: That's the problem ! I wan'to check if the object is nothing or not. Not an object property. We can use ={Binding} for itemssource, why not for visibility ?

Comment: Because if the object hasn't been created yet, you can't access it's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you wan't to make an object which hasn't been yet created collapsed and visible when it was created. Because by default you will get behaviour, if there is no object there is nothing to render and when it's created it instantly gets rendered.

Comment: I have a right panel with an expander. When i click on items in a listbox, i set expander.datacontext=item.datacontext. My problem is when the expander datacontext is nothing, the expander is visible...

Answer (score 1):

`{Binding Path=.}` is basically the same as `{Binding}`

```
<Expander Visibility="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource nVis}}">
```

You could also choose the long syntax.

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Visibility>
        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource nVis}" />
    </Expander.Visibility>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn't find a way to do it easy.
I've done it by code, not xaml.